# using simpleDB in android?

Tags: android, web-services, amazon-simpledb

i am trying to use simpleDB in my android app.
i need only get text data from amazon simpleDB but i am a new user of amazon web services.
i donT know anything about to get data using amazon web services from my simpleDB domains.
is there any basic examples or the part of code.even i canT start:S can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST to retrieve info from your simple DB.  Here is a simple REST client to make HTTP GET and POST requests.

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

Comment: thanx everyone! i did it finaly.

Comment: can you mark this answer as correct? or whichever one helped you more

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Web Services have an [official SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) for Android which is currently in Beta.

You can check out the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/) online, it looks simple to use.